# Permission denied when building a Cordova app with XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, permission-denied

I'm trying to build a Cordova project that was created in a Windows computer, however i keep getting a `Permission Denied (13)` error for all the files.

I tried running `chmod +x` and `chmod 777` on these files and on the `copy-www-build-step.sh` file but still the same error.

```
rsync: readlink: "Users/xxx/xxx/platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js" failed: Permission Denied (13)

rsync: readlink: "Users/xxx/xxx/platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/platform.js" failed: Permission Denied (13)
```

etc..

The same error apply to all the files, even the .css ones.

```
rsync: readlink: "Users/xxx/xxx/platforms/ios/www/css/style.css" failed: Permission Denied (13)
```

Even after executing: `sudo chmod 777 platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js` the problem remains.

What could cause this type of errors ?

Comment: Did you tried giving read & write access to your complete project folder via finder?

Comment: @Gandhi Yes i tried, but still the same errors.

Comment: could you provide more info like os version, xcode version etc